# Can HDMI be converted to Display Port?

Tags: hdmi, displayport

I need to plug the HDMI output of a laptop into an Display Port male connector that's coming out of a wall mounted TV with no access to the back. I started searching for male-HDMI-to-female-Display-Port adaptors and I found very little. [The only one I found](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Displayport-FOINNEX-Converter-Connecting-Nintendo-Active-HDMI-Adapter/dp/B07G796JF8/ref=sr_1_29) is expensive I have a USB connector as well. Is this because the only way to do this conversion is active and it needs power?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DisplayPort is, in contrast to HDMI and previous display connections, a packetised data stream over a wire connection. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).

> DisplayPort is the first display interface to rely on packetized data transmission, a form of digital communication found in technologies such as Ethernet, USB, and PCI Express.

As a result while it may use a similar signalling method over the wires, making it backwards compatible with HDMI, it needs some active electronics in order to packet up the data in order to be forwards compatible.

HDMI outputs are not designed to supply power and while you might be able to leech enough power from *some* graphics cards you cannot guarantee it.

As a result you do have to have both electronics and a supply to power those electronics.